# Python app distribution cross-platform

Tags: python, cross-platform, setuptools, py2app

I want to distribute my app on OSX (using py2app) and as a Debian package.

The structure of my app is like:

```
app/
     debian/
            <lots of debian related stuff>
     scripts/
             app
     app/
         __init__.py
         app.py
         mod1/
              __init__.py
              a.py
         mod2/
              __init__.py
              b.py
```

My setup.py looks something like:

```
from setuptools import setup
import os
import os.path

osname = os.uname()[0]

if osname == 'Darwin':
    APP = ['app/app.py']
    DATA_FILES = []
    OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

    setup(
        app=APP,
        data_files=DATA_FILES,
        options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
    )
elif osname == 'Linux':
        setup(
        name = "app",
        version = "0.0.1",
        description = "foo bar",
        packages = ["app", "app.mod1", "app.mod2"],
        scripts = ["scripts/app"],
        data_files = [
            ("/usr/bin", ["scripts/app"]),
       ]
    )
```

Then, in b.py (this is on OSX):

```
from app.mod2.b import *
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named mod2.b
```

So basically, mod2 can't acccess mod1. On Linux there's no problem, because the python module 'app' is installed globally in /usr/shared/pyshared. But on OSX the app will obviously be a self-contained .app thing built by py2app. I wonder if I approached this totally wrong, are there any best practices when distributing Python apps on OSX?

Edit: I also tried a hack like this in b.py:

```
from ..mod2.b import *

ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Edit2: Seems to be related to this [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the 'best practice' or not (I've not put much python software into proper distribution), but I would just make sure that the top-level app package was in `sys.path`.  Something like putting the following into the top-level `__init__.py`:

```
try:
    import myapp
except ImportError:
    import sys
    from os.path import abspath, dirname, split
    parent_dir = split(dirname(abspath(__file__)))[0]
    sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

I think that should do the right thing in a cross platform way.

EDIT: As kaizer.se points out this might not work in the `__init__.py` file, depending on how the code you're invoking is getting executed. It would only work if that file is evaluated. The key is to make sure that the top-level package is in `sys.path` from some the code that actually is running.

Often times, so that I an execute individual files inside of a package directly (for testing with the `if __name__ eq '__main__'` idiom), I'll do something like place a statement:

```
import _setup
```

At the top of the individual file in question, and then create a file `_setup.py` which does the path munging as necessary.  So, something like:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    _setup.py
    mod1/
        __init__.py
        _setup.py
        somemodule.py
```

If you `import _setup` from `somemodule.py`, that setup file can ensure that the top level package is in `sys.path` before the rest of the code in `somemodule.py` is evaluated.

Comment: can that be a solution? How will the application reach the package's __init__ module in the first place, if it's not in the path?